# 16 pawns on a chess board with no three collinear: how do I go about solving this?

Tags: strategy, checkerboard

Here's a problem that was posed to me but I haven't seen anything about it anywhere online! I'm beginning to wonder if I'm just getting played!

You have a chessboard and sixteen pawns. The puzzle is to have all sixteen pawns on the board such that no three are collinear (three in a row). It can be considered with Cartesian coordinates; the three pawns can't make the same slope, even at unequal distances (ex: 0,0 & 1,2 & 3,6 is not allowed).

I'm thinking that the solution must be so complex that there must be a logic, strategy, or algorithm for this. Could people help me out? Thanks!

Comment: can you place each pawn on top of each other?

Comment: No three (or more) pawns may be in any straight line of any direction. This is a special case of the [no-three-in-line problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-three-in-line_problem). Martin Gardner reprints the best-known solutions for all board sizes up to 16x16 in chapter 5 of *Penrose Tiles to Trapdoor Ciphers*, pub. Freeman, ISBN 0-7167-1987-8.

Comment: @Jamal commenting on an answer to this question cites a result from Achim Flammenkamp's web site. The portal to his research on the no-3-in-line problem is [here](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/no3in/readme.html).

Comment: ah... but must the pawns follow the chess rules?  IE must start in rows 2 and 7 for the appropriate colors? or are all 64 spaces available to all pawns?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry They cannot be placed on top of each other. Each has their own square.

Comment: @xQbert all squares are available

Comment: I note that you got a number of solutions to the problem but no one actually answered your question: how to go about solving it?  The way I would go about solving it is by solving a bunch of simpler problems. Fewer pawns makes it easier, larger board makes it easier.  So try coming up with solutions with different numbers of pawns and larger or smaller boards, and see what you learn from solving those easier problems.  Maybe you can adapt one of the solutions to an easier problem to solve a harder one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Algoritm is :

> Create a 4x4 table which each 2 pawns cannot be in 1 row, 1 column, and 1 diagonal including those diagonals obtained by "wrapping around" the edges.

Then

> Expand it into 8x8 chess board
>  [image]

Here is the complete solution from **Achim Flammenkamp Ph.D.**
There are totally 57 solutions

> [image]

Comment: Ignoring rotations/reflections, is this a unique solution?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I do not know, I just find the answer today, with my second hypothesis (my first hypothesis is wrong). Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 No. OEIS gives the numbers of [inequivalent solutions, i.e. counting congruent solutions as the same](http://oeis.org/A000769), and of [all solutions, counting congruent ones as different](http://oeis.org/A000755), of the problem of placing 2n pawns on an nxn board, no 3 in a straight line. For n=8 there are 57 and 380 respectively. For all n>3 there are non-congruent solutions.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Since no three pawns are colinear, any two rows or columns can be swapped with each other any number of times, as these operations can never make pawns that aren't already colinear colinear.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Actually, that's wrong; it only applies when diagonals are allowed.

Comment: check this : http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/no3in/no8.gif. It shoes all the solutions in tiny pixels.

Comment: I got above link from @RosieF links.

Comment: @JamalSenjaya Ah, good ol' Achim Flammenkamp, who has contributed so much to this and other areas of mathematics.

Comment: *then*, "than" is to express a comparison, not a time sequence.

Comment: Love this answer, thanks to all who answered and contributed!

Answer (score 1):

Note that each of the eight rows of the chessboard must contain exactly two pawns. If a row contained 3 or more pawns, it would violate the conditions of the problem. And if a row contained less than 2 pawns, then some other row would have to have 3 or more pawns, again violating the conditions of the problem.

There are 8*7/2 = 28 ways to place a pair of pawns on a given row.

So, with 8 rows, there are only 28^8 = 377x10^9 possible ways of solving the problem. This is a large number but within the realm of a computer search.

Comment: Starting at the third row, the number of choices will go down rapidly.

Comment: Since there must be two pawns in each column, you have only one choice for the last row, and only at most six choices for the seventh row.

Comment: Is anyone trying this approach, then?

Answer (score -2):

The answer is based on Rotational symmetry.[image]

Comment: Hello, welcome to Puzzling.SE. Can you please add more explanation to your answer. Meanwhile why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to earn your first badge.

Comment: A8, B6 and D2 are on the same line. (You have the chess board sideways, but luckily the position is symmetrical, so the coordinates work in any orientation.)

Comment: Similarly, A1, D2, G3 are collinear, as are F7, G4, H1; B6, E7, H8; and probably others.